# How to make a link on Facebook status via app?

Tags: facebook, hyperlink

Im not sure how to announce what im trying to do so i decided to take a screenshot of what im trying to find.

http://gyazo.com/088dc0a46dd31720385cb9332f6680c9

I want to find how to do the link that says "Get Mypad" how do i make this with fb.api?

Answer (score 0):

They are called action_links and can be sent when you post with an element like:

```
action_links: [{ text: 'action link test', href: 'http://example.com'}]
```

Full code:

```
FB.ui({
      method: 'stream.publish',
      action_links: [{ text: 'My Link Text', href: 'http://example.com'}]
    });
```

Comment: I Tested this code with my current (working) one. and it wont set the status, so i can tell something in the code is stopping it from going through, any clue?

function setStatus(){
                status1 = document.getElementById('status').value;
                FB.api(
                  {
                    method: 'status.set',
                    status: status1
                    action_links: [{ text: 'Update YOUR Via', href: 'http://updateyourvia.com/'}]
                    
                    },